# Extracting Data From Wikipedia via json and "*" in struct causing problems in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, mediawiki, structure

I am trying to extract data from the following Wikipedia page.

URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=List_of_bands_from_Los_Angeles&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

The code is below.

```
<cfhttp url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=List_of_bands_from_Los_Angeles&prop=revisions&rvprop=content" result="wikiBandListResults">

<cfset wikiBandListResultObject = deserializeJSON(wikiBandListResults.filecontent)>

<cfdump var="#wikiBandListResultObject.query.pages.11708073.revisions[1]#">
```

I am able to drill down all the way to the structure named "*" that is one layer on top of the data I am trying to get to.  However, when I put in the following, I get an error.

```
<cfdump var="#wikiBandListResultObject.query.pages.11708073.revisions[1].*#">
```

Is there a way to reference this so I can get to the data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: I put the code on my Railo server, and am receiving an invalid Identifier error on the last line. Looking in the cfdump, that last line looks like exactly what is needed. I wonder if maybe there is a problem with having a *, because when I change the last line to <cfdump var="#wikiBandListResultObject.query.pages.11708073.revisions[1].contentformat#">, it works just fine.

Comment: I was getting "Invalid CFML construct found on line 13 at column 74."  I just tried the solution below with ["*"] and it works well.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `*` is not a valid coldfusion variable name so you need to use array notation instead of dot notation; simply change `.*` to `["*"]`

I tested with

```
<cfhttp url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&titles=List_of_bands_from_Los_Angeles&prop=revisions&rvprop=content" result="wikiBandListResults">
<cfset wikiBandListResultObject = deserializeJSON(wikiBandListResults.filecontent)>
<cfdump var = "#wikiBandListResultObject.query.pages.11708073.revisions[1]["*"]#">
```

and got

> {{Unreferenced|date=October 2008}}[[Los Angeles]] has been home to
>   many new and established music bands. Some of the bands originating
>   from Los Angeles, including [[Orange County, California|Orange]] and
>   [[Riverside County, California|Riverside]] counties, include:
>   {{dynamic list}} {{compactTOC8|side=yes|top=yes|num=yes}} ==0-9== *
>   [[16 (band)|16]] * [[213 (group)|213]] * [[2Cents]] * [[2nd II None]]
>   ...

Comment: It's not quotes inside quotes, it's quotes inside a hash expression (which just happens to be in quotes, even though it doesn't need to be). For readability/syntax highlighter purposes, `['*']` would also work, (as would not specifying the redundant outer quotes).

Comment: What Peter said. I usually do that, I'm having an off morning. TGIF.

Comment: As for not needing the quotes, you're right but I like to have anything in an attribute inside the quotes.  `<div id=myTag>` doesn't look right to me.  Neither does `<cfdump var=#wikiBandListResultObject.query.pages.11708073.revisions[1]["*"]#>`